# I have show this type Order ID - Order Data - Order Status and I click on order id then redireck go to order details page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I have show this type Order ID - Order Data - Order Status and I click on order id then redirect go to order details page ? how to do this ? exmaple order id is 2 then I click on 2 then go to order details show ?how to create this in magento 2?

Comment: show your phtml code where you display those details?

Comment: <?php
$order = $this->helper('Wds\Coreoverride\Helper\Data')->getCollection();
foreach($order as $items){
    echo "Entity Id :". $items->getEntityId();
    echo "Order Status :". $items->getStatus();
    echo "Subtotal:". $items->getSubtotal();
}
?> this is my phtml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your phtml

```
<?php
$order = $this->helper('Wds\Coreoverride\Helper\Data')->getCollection();
foreach($order as $items){ ?>
  <div><span>Order Id :</span><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>"><?php echo $items->getEntityId(); ?></a>
  <?php
  echo "Order Status :". $items->getStatus();
  echo "Subtotal:". $items->getSubtotal();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very help full ..Order ID - Order Data - Order Status this forment I will display I have order Id I have order status so how to find order data and this al show left penel or right panel so how to do?

Comment: Please explain bit more, I can't get it

Comment: how to get order data on home page ?or left or right penel

Comment: Order Data?? the above collection is order data and left or right panel in the sense

Comment: means order details all in order data and I show all details left and right and home page